# Tableview prototype cell higher than the the other cells

Tags: swift, tableview

I made a tableview with UIViewController and dragged a tableview scheme into the viewcontroller. I have remembered all the codes that are needed i the class (im quite sure??). But i can't figure out, why the prototype cell is a different size than all the other cells?
It will look as the picture below, when i run the app

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Storyboard file and select your Prototype cell. Than in the right sidebar (Utilities pane) select the Size inspector. Here you can enter a custom height for your cell:

[image]

-- Edit --

Maybe remove the Scroll View Insets of the UIViewController? Select the UIViewController and in the attributes inspector uncheck: ' Adjust scroll view insets ' :

[image]

Comment: Its not the fault. Its like there is a cell above the prototype cell?

Comment: Unchecking "Adjust Scroll View Insets" made it work. Thanks!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Set the desired height for each cell in `tableView.heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Won't work either. The prototype cell is still higher

Comment: Did you set the tableview's data and delegate since you dragged a tableView on to a view controller?

Comment: Yes i did, and i have made the CellForRow and NumberofSections